# jQuery accordion for smartphones

Tags: jquery

The idea is that this accordion works only on smartphones to improve usability on small devices.

However it only works when you refresh the browser under 480.

Is there a way of including in the function something that makes the browser refresh as soon as the window is resized under 480?

Refreshing the browser manually would not make it usable at all.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
function accordion() {
if (windowWidth<=480)
{


$('h3').click(function() {

    $('h3').next().hide(2000);

    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

          $(this).next().show(1000); } 


                         });

                    }}

$(document).ready(function() {
 accordion();
 });
```

HTML markup

```
                    <section class="box">

                        <h3>Service 1</h3>

                       <div class="box2"> <p></p></div>

                    </section><!-- end box_1 --> 

                    <section class="box">

                        <h3>Service 2</h3>

                        <div class="box2"><p></p>   </div>                     

                    </section><!-- end box_2 --> 

                    <section class="box">

                        <h3>Service 3</h3>

                        <div class="box2"><p></p>   </div>                     

                    </section><!-- end box_3 -->  

                    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the initial window width.

```
$(window).resize(function () { windowWidth = $(this).width(); });
```

You will also need to run `accordion` appropriately and turn it off if the window widens again.  Maybe just adding a call to `accordion` in the `window.resize` method will be enough, but I haven't tested that.